# Icinga 2 check_logfiles with Agent on Windows

Tags: windows, monitoring, icinga2

I'd like to add a check_logfiles command on a windows machine.
Do I have to use the NSClient++ or is it possible to do this with the Icinga 2 Client wich is already installed?
I configured the Service and the check_command on my satellite.
But I get this error message:

```
Command D:\icinga2\/sbin/check_logfiles-3.9/plugin-scripts/check_logfiles --criticalpattern ERROR --logfile D:\logdirectory\error.log --tag aplication-Log failed to execute: 2, "The system cannot find the file specified."
```

I tried to change the path with correct windows path with "\" instead of "/", but got the same error message.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The check_logfiles shell script in windows wont work. Try creating an exe as described here and see: https://labs.consol.de/de/nagios/check_logfiles/check_logfiles-windows-exe/

Comment: I am using the perl script, not the shell Script.

Comment: Ok, but perl scripts are not by default executable in windows. You will need to compile and install perl before. May be a better option for you is to use NSClient++ instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hello i could solve my problem.
In the check command you need so seperate perl from the command like this:

```
check_command = "perl", "D:\icinga2\sbin\check_logfiles-3.9\plugin-scripts\check_logfiles"
```

Didnt knew that. Now it is working fine. Thanks for the help @Diamant

Comment: Great you got it working. Haven't you needed perl to install before?